# how to make first column of data table as hyperlink

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

to draw a data table i used below code

```
function getDataTable(data1) { 
var cols = [];
var exampleRecord = data1[0];
var keys = Object.keys(exampleRecord);
 keys.forEach(function(k) {
        cols.push({
          title: k,
          data: k
          //optionally do some type detection here for render function
        });
      });
 var table = $('#queryBuilderTable').DataTable({
        columns: cols
      });

      //add data and draw

      table.rows.add(data1).draw();}
```

in my first column i got caseId i just want this column as a hyper link so that user can click on that link please help  in my code i use json and my JSON KEY is working as column name here.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in the following way

```
    $('#queryBuilderTable').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "The_Link_Defines",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    var returnString='';
    /*here you can check the condition for making link */
    if(your condition with data obj)
      returnString ='<a href="'+data+'"> Hyper_Link </a>';
    else 
       returnString ='<span>Text </span>';

    return returnString ;
    }
  } ]
} );
```

and refer the following Article, 
[Article Link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#)

Comment: Thank you for the help but by using above code it makes my whole table as hiperlink

Comment: Okey see the updates in the answer and the given link. If it helps upvote and mark as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i solved this by using below code

```
 var table = $('#queryBuilderTable').DataTable({
     "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "",
            "render": function ( data1, type, full, meta ) {
                  return '<a onclick="cancerConferenceDataTable('+data1+')" style="cursor: pointer;">'+data1+'</a>';

            }
          } ],
        columns: cols

      });

      //add data and draw
      table.rows.add(data1).draw();
```